# Counting zero nodes in binary tree in prolog

Tags: tree, prolog, binary-tree

I wrote predicates for counting nodes with zero values, but counter Num1 works incorrect.

```
countZeros(empty, Num).
countZeros(tree(0, Left, Right), Num) :- 
    Num1 = Num + 1,
    countZeros(Left, Num1),
    countZeros(Right, Num1).
countZeros(tree(_, Left, Right), Num) :-
    countZeros(Left, Num),
    countZeros(Right, Num).
```

That's my query:

```
countZeros(tree(5,
        tree(0,
            tree(6, empty, empty),
            tree(4, empty, empty)
        ),
        tree(0,
            tree(2, empty, empty),
            tree(0, empty, empty)
        )
        )
    , 0).
```

Who can help with it?

Comment: Please explain in what way(s) this code is "incorrect".

Comment: `Num1 is Num + 1`, not `Num1 = Num + 1`. `=/2` is a unification operator, not value assignment. Unless you're using Visual/Turbo/PDC Prolog.

Comment: @lurker I write in Visual Prolog, `is` instead `=` causes an error.

Comment: @ScottHunter Num1 equals 2 at the at the end of the program.

Comment: @dedmarkel ok, ignore my comment then. Visual Prolog does not follow the standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive calculation of the count is backwards. You are starting with an uninstantiated count, and adding 1 until you get to an empty node and not changing the count. So the count is never initialized and never returned.

If you think of your predicate clauses logically and describe what they mean, it helps define them properly. For example, *If the current node is empty, the number of zeroes is `0`*. This would be expressed as:

```
countZeros(empty, 0).
```

You can also say, *If the current node is a `0`, then the number of zeroes is the number of zeroes in the left branch, plus the number of zeroes in the right branch, plus `1`*. This can be expressed as:

```
countZeros(tree(0, Left, Right), Num) :-
    countZeros(Left, Num1),
    countZeros(Right, Num2),
    Num is Num1 + Num2 + 1.
```

Similarly, *If the current node is NOT a `0`, then the number of zeroes is the number of zeroes in the left branch, plus the number of zeroes in the right branch*.

```
countZeros(tree(X, Left, Right), Num) :-
    dif(X, 0),
    countZeros(Left, Num1),
    countZeros(Right, Num2),
    Num is Num1 + Num2.
```

You'll need to translate the operations in these to Visual Prolog. (I don't know the operator for "terms are different", whereas I use `dif(X, 0)` above. And I am using `is/2` instead of `=/2`.)